# How do I format a street address?

Tags: javascript, node.js

Type any physical address into [Google.com](https://www.google.com) and submit, the address gets formatted.

For example, try the following...

```
1400 West Mockingbird Lane => 1400 W Mockingbird Ln
1323 East Lake St => 1323 E Lake St
1700 Belmont Avenue => 1700 Belmont Ave
4565 Dunhill Court => 4565 Dunhill Ct
1100 west 7th street => 1100 W 7th St
```

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: Below is my answer :-)

Comment: Why am I getting all these negative reviews? what gives?

Comment: Down votes are because there is actually no question. This post should be closed.  P.S.  The act of coding is enhanced with caffeine, not cannibis.

Comment: I see, edited the title back to question format.

Answer (score 2):

```
var func = {}
func.toTitleCase = function(str) {
  if(typeof(str) === 'undefined')
    return
  return str.toLowerCase().replace(/(?:^|\s|\/|\-)\w/g, function(match) { 
    return match.toUpperCase();  
  })
}
func.formatStreetAddress = function(address) {
    address = address.replace(/[.,]/g, '')
    var replaceWords = {
        'apartment': '#',
        'apt': '#',
        'expressway': 'Expy',
        'po box': '#',
        'suite': '#',
        'ste': '#',
        'avenue': 'Ave',
        'boulevard': 'Blvd',
        'circle': 'Cir',
        'court': 'Ct',
        'crt': 'Ct',
        'drive': 'Dr',
        'lane': 'Ln',
        'mount': 'Mt',
        'highway': 'Hwy',
        'parkway': 'Pkwy',
        'place': 'Pl',
        'street': 'St',
        'east': 'E',
        'west': 'W',
        'south': 'S',
        'north': 'N',
        'road': 'Rd'
      },
    formatted_address = []
    address.split(' ').forEach(function(word) {
      word = word.toLowerCase().trim()
      if(replaceWords[word]) {
        formatted_address.push(replaceWords[word])
        return
      }
      formatted_address.push(word)
    })
    formatted_address = formatted_address.join(' ')
    formatted_address = formatted_address.replace(/\# /g, '#')
    return func.toTitleCase(formatted_address)
}
```

```
func.formatStreetAddress('1100 west 7th street')
```

Comment: Add/remove as many abbreviations as you'd like: https://pe.usps.com/text/pub28/28apc_002.htm